# Not able to send a POST request to Spring controller using Jquery, Ajax and Json

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a very simple flow using Spring, jQuery, Ajax and Json. But I am not able to send a POST request to Spring controller. Also my eclipse shows compilation error when I am trying to use consumes and produces in @RequestMapping. I am not using maven. It is a simple dynamic web project in eclipse. I am using spring 3.0.5 jars.

HTML page.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    div {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
  </style>

    <script src="/JSONProject/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var user="";
    var pwd1="";
    var json="";
    var strJson="";
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#button").click(function(){  
                console.log("inside click");
                user=$("#userName").val();
                pwd1=$("#password").val();
                json={username:user,password:pwd1};
                console.log("json: "+json);
                strJson=JSON.stringify(json);
                console.log("strJson: "+strJson);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/JSONProject/add.html",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json)
                })
                .done(function(resultUserDTO) {
                    JSON.stringify(resultUserDTO)
                    alert("result: "+resultUserDTO);
                    });



            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <FORM>
            Please enter your text:
            <BR>
                <div  >
                    <label id="uName">Username</label>
                    <input id="userName"/>
                    <br>
                    <label id="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="Password" id="pwd"/>

                </div>
            <BR>
            <INPUT id="button" TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">
        </FORM>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
package demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import demo.model.Login;

@Controller

public class HelloWorldController {

    Login users;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println("Inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

    /**
     * Handles POST request
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = "application/json")
    public String processJson(@RequestBody String requestBody){

        return "Handled application/json request "; 


    }
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

The attribute consumes is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="demo.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".htm" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring with ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the hello.html link in index.jsp, hello.html opens and i get the syso of the controller method that handles "\hello" and get. But when i make a POST request using jquery, i still see the syso of the method that handle "\hello" and get method on console..

Really confused.
Please help
Thank you in advance!!

***New updated code after the suggestions given. Code has complied. Yet not call to POST handler. Syso inside POST handler is not getting printed on eclipse console.***

Controller:

```
package demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import demo.model.Login;

@Controller

public class HelloWorldController {

    Login users;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println("Inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

    /**
     * Handles request for adding two numbers
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = "application/json",produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String processJson(@RequestBody String requestBody){
        System.out.println("inside controller 2");

        return "Handled application/json request "; 


    }
}
```

hello.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    div {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
  </style>

    <script src="/JSONProject/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var user="";
    var pwd1="";
    var json="";
    var strJson="";
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#button").click(function(){  
                console.log("inside click");
                user=$("#userName").val();
                pwd1=$("#password").val();
                json={username:user,password:pwd1};
                console.log("json: "+json);
                strJson=JSON.stringify(json);
                console.log("strJson: "+strJson);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/JSONProject/add.html",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json)
                })
                .done(function(resultUserDTO) {
                    JSON.stringify(resultUserDTO)
                    alert("result: "+resultUserDTO);
                    });



            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <FORM method="post">
            Please enter your text:
            <BR>
                <div  >
                    <label id="uName">Username</label>
                    <input id="userName"/>
                    <br>
                    <label id="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="Password" id="pwd"/>

                </div>
            <BR>
            <INPUT id="button" TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">
        </FORM>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S: I have used 3.2.0 version

Comment: I don't remember that much from this area, but <FORM> tag is by default GET, I see that you are using button handler, but this could be possible clutch ?
Second thing could be, that you sending request to JSONProject/add.html, but mapping is only /add.

Comment: If you get compilation errors how do you suppose your program can do anything?

Comment: I think the problem is that your sending the ajax call to "/JSONProject/add.html", but your mapping in your controller is to "/add".  I assume your WAR context is 'JSONProject', so the first part is fine, but unless you are doing something in your config that I didn't see, Spring MVC does not use a `.html` extension on it's mappings.  I suspect if you use something like Chromes dev tools or FireFox's FireBug and see what response you are getting back for the AJAX call, you would be getting a 404 Not Found.

Comment: @Lukino 
I added POST method in the form tag. Still no good. Regarding sending JSONProject/add.html and mapping only /add, well it work fine on index.jsp. Still i changed the mapping to /add.html in controller. No good. My GET handler is getting called.

Comment: @CodeChimp
If you see index.jsp, I am using hello.html in ` <a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>` and it makes a perfect GET request to controller and renders hello.html. Also syso in GET handler is printed. With /JSONProject/add.html my GET handler is only called as I can see the syso in this method getting printed on eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

The `produces` and `consumes` attributes have been introduced with spring 3.1. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

You are using spring 3.0.x, so your program won't compile and therefore won't do anything.

Also, as configured, your `add` method's return value will be used as a view name ( A view with name "Handled application/json request "). If you want to handle the content generation by yourself annotate your `add` method with `@ResponseBody`.

Also your js handler is calling the wrong url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/JSONProject/add.html"
});
```

vs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = "application/json")
public String processJson(@RequestBody String requestBody){
```

Either change the js/ajax url to `http://localhost:8080/JSONProject/add` or your request mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = "/add.html",method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = "application/json")`

Comment: I replaced all jars Spring 3.2.0 version. I added ` @ResponseBody ` That solved my compilation issue. Still POST handler is not getting called. :( 

I will put the updated code as EDIT

Comment: I did change my mapping to handle /add.html. 
Still the same issue. I opened the chrome console for seeing the cause and I can see

OST http://localhost:8080/JSONProject/hello.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I am closing this thread as the problem was solved. Instead of giving the absolute path, i used add.html in ajax call. Without any changes in controller, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my observation, let me know if it helps:

**1. Internal Resource View Resolver**

Your Internal Resource View Resolver looks for files with suffix .htm in jsp folder. Hence all your files, except index.jsp, should end with .htm. Or if they are .html, you can change the View Resolver to look for .html instead.

```
        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        </bean>
```

**2. Input Type Button not Submit**

Change the Input Type to just Button and not Submit.
On Click of this Input[type="Submit"], tends to submit the form to the action of the form(which isn't specified hence reloads the page which is why you get the same syso).
You want to override this input with your onclick event. Hence change it's type to button.

```
   <INPUT id="button" TYPE="Button" VALUE="Submit">
```

**3. Consumes and Produces**

Not really required.
Those are basically restrictions on the handlers.
It was giving me trouble. It works without them. Totally your call on this one.